# How to inject arbitrary memory address in x86-64?

Tags: c, x86-64, exploit, memory-address, format-string

Hello I'm trying to learn some basic memory exploits from the book "Hacking: the Art of Exploitation" and I'm having trouble due to my x86-64 system.

For this part of the book I was learning format string exploits and I was to inject an environment variable  in to be read through the vulnerability. (p 172)

This is the code for a program I'm trying to exploit using format string vulnerabilities:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {
    char text[1024];
    static int test_val = -72;

    if(argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <text to print>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
    }
    strcpy(text, argv[1]);

    printf("The right way to print user-controlled input:\n");
    printf("%s", text);


    printf("\nThe wrong way to print user-controlled input:\n");
    printf(text);

    printf("\n");

    // Debug output
    printf("[*] test_val @ %p = %d %p\n", &test_val, test_val, test_val);

    exit(0);
    }
```

from here, to exploit, I tried as the book says (written for x86-32) after compiling:

```
  ./fmt_vuln $(printf "\x\x\x\x\x\x\x\x")%016x%016x%016x%016x%016x%016x%016x%s
```

(\x\x\x\x\x\x\x replaced with little endian format arbitrary environment memory address)
and all I got was a Segmentation problem when I got to the "\nThe wrong way to print user-controlled input:\n" part.

The correct response of the program is supposed be the string within the address injected.

I also had ASLR, NX and format guard off.

I don't know how to get this to work. I'm guessing either I'm not injecting the address right because of the difference between 32 and 64 or %s isn't reading my address correctly. Or possibly I'm guessing I didn't turn off the security good enough.

Can you please find a solution to how to inject a memory address accurately in a x86-64 system?

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to learn programming.

Comment: can you tell me how the arguments are passed? @AntoineMathys

Comment: Oh thank you but What do you mean by "introduce enough fake conversion specifications" and if I were to inject the address, are you saying because the string pointers read a 8 byte pointer and addresses are 48 bit, I wouldn't be able to pass the extra \x00\x00? @AntoineMathys